# Nginx not routing browser request to wsgi(python server running)

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am running my flask project from uwsgi on nginx. But my nginx is not routing the request to uwsgi when i hit localhost:80/

My nginx.conf looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <your machine ip/domain>;(if on local it would be localhost but I was running on WSL so I put it IP)

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      web_app:5000; (you might see suggestion of .sock files or suffixing http:// or unix: but none work for me plain simple your python server's service name which you would provide in docker-compose)
    }
}
```

docker-compose looks like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web_app:
    build: .
    container_name: kpi-dashboard
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web_app
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    container_name: postgresql
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

nginx dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (it is important to remove the default conf as it would not take your custom conf no matter where you copy it)
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
(there are answers online to copy it no other places but this only works)

EXPOSE 80
```

web app dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.16-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc -y && apt-get install python3-dev -y && apt-get install libpq-dev -y

ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}
RUN pip install poetry

WORKDIR /app
COPY pyproject.toml /app/
COPY . /app/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-dev

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["uwsgi", "--ini", "wsgi.ini"]
```

wsgi.ini file

```
[uwsgi]
module = app (this is when you are writing you project entrypoint in app.py. if you are writing in wsgi.py then this would become wsgi:app)
socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
callable = app (this is important as wsgi by default considers your app instance as application either handle it in your main file or just add this configuration)
processes = 1
threads = 1
master = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

This is what the nginx container output looks like

[image]

**Editing question as the 404 issue was solved. But nginx is still not routing to wsgi.**

**The solution**
changed the location of copying the nginx.conf file in nginx dockerfile

*COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.config*

**Editing question again as nginx routing to wsgi issue also resolved.**
**The solution**
*updated files as mentioned above*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes so this worked for me. There are n number of configurations available online and almost all are same yet a slight difference causes the issue.
I am updating my question to change files with the content that worked. Hope it helps someone.